# Azure Data Streaming with Kafka and Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, architecture, databricks

I have a python simulator which streams data to kafka(set up on azure VM). The streaming data needs to pushed to a azure blob storage.

Can I set up azure databricks and schedule it with adf to pull data from Kafka? Is a better approach I can take up?